# Doctrine update entity in loop, persist or flush?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have multiple loops like :

```
    $bets = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Bet')->getBetsForMatch($match_id);

    foreach ($bets as $key => $bet) {
        $devices = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Device')->findBy(array('user' => $bets->getUser()));

        foreach ($devices as $key => $device) {
            //HERE I SEND A PUSH NOTIFICATION

            if($this->rms_push->send($message)){
                $device->getUser()->setBadge($device->getUser()->getBadge() + 1);
                $this->em->flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I get all bets for a match, for each bet I get all devices saved for the user, and after that I need to update my user with : `$device->getUser()->setBadge($device->getUser()->getBadge() + 1);`

For now, I flush each time but I think there is a better way, ideas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need only one flush, out of your loop:

```
foreach ($bets as $key => $bet) {
    $devices = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Device')->findBy(array('user' => $bets->getUser()));

    foreach ($devices as $key => $device) {
        //HERE I SEND A PUSH NOTIFICATION

        if($this->rms_push->send($message)){
            $device->getUser()->setBadge($device->getUser()->getBadge() + 1);
        }
    }
}

$this->em->flush();
```

Calling `$this->_em->persist($obj)` involves to create a new entry.

If you need to create or update depending on the entry exists or not, look [at `EntityManager::merge`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities) .

To preserve memory usage for large number of entries, look at [batch processing](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html).

**Note** SensioLabs insight (PHP source code quality analysis) raises a warning if your code calls `EntityManager::flush` inside a loop.

Comment: So, if I create a new entity in my loop, I need to persist, but like that, all updated entities are in memory ? If I update twice the same user, is it ok ?

Comment: Right, all is in memory. I just added a link at the end of my answer to process a large amount of data, and if you need to make the entitymanager create if exists, use `EntityManager::merge` instead, see the link in my answer too. Sensio Labs insight (symfony code quality analyser) raises a warning if you flush inside a loop.