# Fatal error: Maximum execution time exceeded in Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

When i process a batch of database operations, i am getting the error:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in  \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 661

How it could be? Each time i create or update the entity, i persist and flush.
How to check what is the reason for this execution, why some batch entity it takes 120 seconds to execute and it stops the script?

```
$timezone = 'Europe/London'; 
$currency = 'EUR'; 

//get all apparments and set the price for them for different dates 
$entAll = $this->em
    ->getRepository( 'BookBundle\Entity\App' )
    ->findBy( [],['aliasApp' => 'ASC'] );

if( $entAll!==null ) {
    foreach ( $entAll as $ent ) {

        $aliasApp = $ent->getAliasApp(); 
        for ( $m=1; $m<=12; $m++ ) {
            for ( $d=1; $d<=31; $d++ ) {
                for ( $y=2019; $y<=2020; $y++ ) {

        $isvalid = checkdate($m,$d,$y);  //m, d, y
        if($isvalid) {

            $aliasAppPr = $aliasApp.'_'.$d.'_'.$m.'_'.$y;

            $curD = new \DateTime( $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d, new \DateTimeZone($timezone) );
            $curts = $curD->getTimestamp();

            $acp = new AppCalPr(); 

            $acp->setAliasAppPr( $aliasAppPr);
            $acp->setDateAppPrStr( $d.'-'.$m.'-'.$y.'  '.$timezone ); 
            $acp->setDateAppPrInt( $curts);

            if( $m>4 || $m<11 ) { $acp->setIsAppPrActive(1); }
            else { $acp->setIsAppPrActive(0); }

            if( $d<10 || $d>20 ) {  $acp->setIsAppPrBooked(1); }
            else {   $acp->setIsAppPrBooked(0); }

            $price = rand(30,300); 
            $acp->setPriceAppPr($price); 
            $acp->setCurrAppPr($currency);
            $this->em->persist($acp);
            $this->em->flush();

            //single day = single price setting, single booking, single appartment
            print_r( '<br><br> 88 AppCalPrFix,  aliasAppPr=' .$aliasAppPr );
            $acbEnt = $this->em
                ->getRepository( 'BookBundle\Entity\AppCalBookRel' )
                //->findBy( [],['aliasApp' => 'ASC'] );
                ->findOneByAliasAppPrACB( $aliasAppPr );
            if ( $acbEnt== null) {
                $acbEnt =new AppCalBookRel();
                $acbEnt->setAppcalOTO($acp); 
                $acbEnt->setAliasAppPrACB($aliasAppPr); 
                $this->em->persist($acbEnt);
                $this->em->flush();
            }

        } //if($isvalid) {

                } // for ( $y=2019; $y<2025; $y++ ){
            } // for ( $d=1; $d<=31; $d++ ) {
        } // for ( $m=4; $m<10; $m++ ) {
    }// foreach ( $entAll as $ent ) {
} // if( $entAll!==null ) {
```

Comment: It appears that you are looping over every single day for a date range spanning years and checking stuff about that date (assuming performing one or more queries about each day). This would be several hundred iterations of a loop multiplied by however many queries each day gets which could potentially be thousands of queries. I doubt persist/flush would be much help here (and likely slow it all down). It's really not surprising that it takes a while to process even if 120 seconds seems like a long time.

Comment: I persist and flush inside the innerst loop. Thus it should take miliseconds, and should not accumulate for 120seconds?

Comment: seems the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040806/doctrine-update-entity-in-loop-persist-or-flush

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

Comment: I don't use doctrine, but persist and flush can probably be safely assumed deal with buffering. So if you are flushing on every iteration of a loop, I assume that would mean something like persist the update/query and flush to disk. This means that you would be using less memory, but every process/flush would take a little extra time. If you are having issues with timeouts, that would usually mean that you could let it buffer a little more between persist/flush calls. Buffering is normally used to save multiple updates in memory and do one write in bulk which is usually faster.